# Flask test doesn't populate request.authorization when username and password are URL encoded

Tags: python, testing, flask

I'm trying to use the following test:

```
def post_webhook(self, payload, **kwargs):
    webhook_username = 'test'
    webhook_password = 'test'

    webhook_url = 'http://{}:{}@localhost:8000/webhook_receive'
    webhook_receive = self.app.post(
        webhook_url.format(webhook_username, webhook_password),
        referrer='http://localhost:8000',
        json=payload)
    return webhook_receive.status_code
```

However the main issue is `request.authorization` is `None`. Though if I launch the server and use `curl -X POST <webhook_url>` or `requests.post(<webhook_url>)`, then `request.authorization` is properly populated.

Trying to figure out the main issue of how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) code and the [Flask Test Client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/#testing), the next pytest code works for me. The way I send the HTTP Basic Auth is the same way curl and HTTPie send it; in the **`Authorization`** header with the user and password encoded in **base64**.

```
import base64
from app import app

def test_secret_endpoint():
    client = app.test_client()

    # testing a route without authentication required
    rv = client.get('/')
    assert rv.status_code == 200

    # testing a secured route without credentials
    rv = client.post('/secret-page')
    assert rv.status_code == 401

    # testing a secured route with valid credentials
    value = base64.encodestring('admin:secret').replace('\n', '')

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(value)}

    rv = client.post('/secret-page', headers=headers)
    assert rv.status_code == 200
    assert 'This is secret' in rv.data
```

The route definitions are:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World :)'


@app.route('/secret-page', methods=['POST'])
@requires_auth
def secret_page():
    return 'This is secret'
```

The request header sending the credentials looks something like this:

```
POST /secret-page HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:5000
...
```

Comment: There's an attribute in `request` called `authorization` as seen in this snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/.

The main issue is that I can access those values every time except when I use the test version's `POST` method.